# Android Tablet API and Android phone API

Tags: android, titanium, tablet

Being new to tablet programming this occured to me. I could see that there exists a different sets of API for iPhone and iPAD. Is this a similar pattern in android and blackberry tablets as well.

What i mean is, is there a different sets of API for Android tablet than Android Phones. If yes, then from where can i download them, and how can i run an emulator for tablet on MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, Android tablets used to run Android 3.0, while phones were still running 2.x.
3.0 is now deprecated and should no longer be used.

Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) was recently released, and it's the API that all future phones and tablets should be using (so to answer your question, it's the same SDK). It's the first API that is "shared" in this manner.

When you develop an app, it should be flexible enough to run on any Android platform. The GUI stretches to fit any screen size. Note that there are ways to programmatically detect if the device running your app is a tablet, and you could use that to adapt your app if you wanted to.

See [the official guide to supporting tablets and handhelds](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) for in-depth information.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 3.0 API ll (Honeycomb) will support Android tablet

download the sdk and do coding for your tablet version.

yes there is an different sets of API for Android tablet and phones.

3.x on wards support tablet. 2.x and 4.x(ICS) will support both tablet and phones

Answer (score 0):

The newer Android SDK versions are for both phones and tablets.  You use the same SDK for both.  The SDK is designed to handle both, but you have to perform significant duplication in your resources to handle all platforms.  It is a bit of a pain.  For example they don't support vector images for icons, so you normally have to make raster duplications for low, medium, high, and extra high dpi devices.